# If/Else Statement Returning false positives

Tags: javascript, if-statement

In my code, I have this `if/else` statement to deal with a situation in which the numbers and letters both return `cont = false`. I have tried running just this code, with the same result. Obviously, it should execute the code in the `else` statement. Does anyone have any ideas?

```
var input = prompt()

if (input == null || " ") {
  //Cont determines whether or not to continue
  console.log("cont = false");
  var cont = false;
}else{
  console.log("cont = true");
  var cont = true;
}
```

Comment: The condition `|| " "` is **always true**.

Comment: You should read on the various comparison operators in JS and how they work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators.

Answer (score 7):

Because that code is not how you check one input against two values.

```
if ( input == null || " " )
```

should be

```
if (input==null || input == " ")
```

Comment: Would suggest === instead of ==. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
input == null || " "
```

evaluates to (result of your comparison) || " ". Now since " " (a non-empty string) is a truthy value this always evaluates to true.

For order of evaluation - 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other replies which are all correct about the || operator and precedence.

Using == is not a good thing to do in most cases, not least because `0 == null` etc - if you're checking if it's actually null or an empty string then something like this is safer:

```
if (input === null || input.trim() === "") {
...
```

This checks type as well as content, so won't be able to give false positives. though if input isn't a string it will complain.

Answer (score 0):

Thank's so much! As a summary of all of the answers recieved so far:

- The `OR` operator (`||`) is comparing `input == null` to `" "`, the latter of which always evaluates to true
- `===` is better than `==`

Thanks again for all the help and support!